# How do you select all rows when data occurs in one of the rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with data

```
    |FormID|Name|
       1      A
       1      B
       2      A
       2      C
       3      B
       3      C
```

I am trying to query all rows where Name 'A' appears, however i also want to get all rows with the same FormID when the name occurs

For example
Select * from table where name = 'A'

```
    resultset
  |FormID|Name|
     1      A
     2      A
     1      B
     2      C
```

Right now i am just querying for the FormID values where the name occurs and then doing another query with the FormID number (Select * from table where formID in (1,2) ) but there must be a way to do this in one sql statement

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh ok thanks for pointing that out i didnt notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

```
SELECT formid, name
FROM forms
WHERE formid IN (SELECT formid FROM forms WHERE name = 'A')
ORDER BY name;
```

gives

```
formid      name      
----------  ----------
1           A         
2           A         
1           B         
2           C
```

Because the subquery in the `IN` doesn't depend on the current row being looked at, it only has to be evaluated once, making it more potentially more efficient for large tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.name = 'A' or
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.formid = t.formid and t2.name = 'A'
             );
```

Actually, the first condition is not necessary, so this suffices:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.formid = t.formid and t2.name = 'A'
             );
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you it works perfect, can you explain what is going on in the exists clause? is Select 1 same as select *?? and how does the second table know to retrieve the same values when you indicated 'and t2.name = 'A' '? shouldnt that statement return only row with 'A' sorry im having a hard time understanding